# Java regex and replacement

Tags: java, regex, replace

Hi I am trying to understand Java regex replacement. I have lots of regex and replacement to apply on text in a file. I want to read regex and apply replacement on text.
Like, I want to replace `text` to `variable` in following example.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class regex1{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+(\\S+)");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
    if (m1.find()){
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));
        s1 = m1.replaceFirst("variable $1");
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Else");
    }
}    
}
```

But I get output as

```
text
variable text
```

Can any one explain how does group and replacement works in java? How to get correct output?

Comment: If you just want to replace `text` with `variable` in your string, you don't need regex. If you want to do more than that, then show the real code.

Comment: You only have one group at the end of the expression which matches "text". So there is only one group :-) (or the whole match (0))

Comment: @Bart yes i got that, my understanding is it will replace group 1 `text` to `variable`. But it is not happening like that. What is correct regex ?

Comment: Netro, so you want to just replace text to variable everywhere in the sentence "cat catches dog text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class regex1{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+(\\S+)");
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
    if (m1.find()){
        System.out.println(m1.group(1));
        s1 = s1.replaceFirst(m1.group(1),"variable");
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Else");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `myMatcher.replaceAll("replacement")` has exactly the same results as `myString.replaceAll("regex", "replacement")`. The difference is just speed.  Taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: there is subtle diff in using `s1.replaceFirst(m1.group(1),"variable");` and `m1.replaceFirst(m1.group(1),"variable");`. This one solves it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+(\\S+)");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
if (m1.find()){
    s1 = m1.replaceFirst(s1.substring(0, m1.start(1)) + "variable");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Else");
}
System.out.println(s1);
// cat catches dog variable
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what are you trying to do. If you want to replace word after `\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+` with `variable` then maybe try this way

```
String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+)(\\S+)");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println(m1.group(2));
    s1 = m1.replaceFirst("$1variable");
    System.out.println(s1);
} else {
    System.out.println("Else");
}
```

now group 1 is `(\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+)` and you are putting it back to replacement with `$1` and adding `variable` at the end.

output:

```
text
cat catches dog variable
```

---

BTW you don't have to invoke `if (m1.find())` if you want to use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll`. Just use it like

```
String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+)(\\S+)");
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
s1 = m1.replaceFirst("$1variable");
System.out.println(s1);
```

or if you wont need Pattern and Matcher any more just

```
String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
s1.replaceFirst("(\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+)(\\S+)","$1variable");
```

Answer (score 0):

String.replaceFirst takes 2 arguments: the regex and the replace string.

So in your example replace,

```
s1 = s1.replaceFirst("variable $1");
```

with

```
s1 = s1.replaceFirst(m1.group(1), "variable");
```

Comment: `myMatcher.replaceAll("replacement")` has exactly the same results as `myString.replaceAll("regex", "replacement")`. The difference is just speed.  Taken from http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: as suggested by Ruchira, ans is `s1 = s1.replaceFirst(m1.group(1), "variable");`

Answer (score 0):

`$1` is a [back-referencing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) method that includes the contents of the 1st (`$1`) set of parenthesis.

In your case `$1` references the first reference created in matcher `m1`. A reference to the word "text".

Explanation of the code

```
                        referenced by $1
                             ↓↓↓↓
String s1 = "cat catches dog text";
                                                        reference $1
                                                           ↓    ↓
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\s*cat\\s+catches\\s*dog\\s+(\\S+)");
```

Explanation of the regex [here](http://regex-explain.googlecode.com/hg/explain.html#%5Cs%2acat%5Cs+catches%5Cs%2adog%5Cs+%28%5CS+%29).  Hover over the colored text to get explanations.

It is important to note that `\S` (capital 'S') matches any non-whitespace character and the the `+` is greedy.  This means we are getting "all non-whitespace characters before the next whitespace" or simply put, we are getting the next word.

In this case the word being matched happens to be "text"

```
Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(s1);
```

`m1` will now match `"cat catches dog text"`

```
s1 = m1.replaceFirst("variable $1");
```

`s1` is set to `s1` (`"cat catches dog text"`) where the first appearance of `m1` (the first appearance of `'"cat catches dog" followed by any word'`) is replaced by `'"variable" followed by that same word'`

If you truly want to have variable replace the word "text" then you need to remove the `$1`.

```
s1 = m1.replaceFirst("variable");
```

`s1` is set to `s1` (`"cat catches dog text"`) where the first appearance of `m1` (the first appearance of `'"cat catches dog" followed by any word'`) is replaced by `'"variable"'`

I this is the case, you don't actually need to include the parenthesis on the RegEx pattern either.  They have no use (in this case) if you are not going to be back-referencing.

Comment: Thanks for taking trouble to such great length. This was my thinking also, but this didn't work. It gives ans as `variable`. Solution given by Ruchira works well.